# Kotlin, is there a nice and simple way to ommit the val problem?

Tags: loops, kotlin

I've been just wondering if there is a way to ommit the **Val cannot be reassigned** error when accessing every element of a list and trying to execute some action on it. For example:

```
for (number in numbers) {
    if (number%2==0){
        number *= 2
    }
}
```

or

```
numbers.forEach {
    if (it%2==0){
        it *= 2
    }
}
```

causes such an error. I know, i could do it like:

```
for (i in numbers.indices){
    if (numbers[i]%2==0){
        numbers[i] *= 2
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: The nice and simple way would be to map to a new list. Is there a reason to update this list in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to change the variable in such range based loops. Iterating over indices is the only way.

Although for your particular case, you can use the map function,

```kotlin
numbers.map { if(it % 2 == 0) 2 * it else it
```

Note that the map function returns a new list without modifying the original list so you will have to use the return value for further usage.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the result of `map` needs to be put in a new variable or reassigned to `numbers`. `map` doesn't mutate the list like the OP wants here

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function like this. I don't think there's something like this in the standard library for mutating each element of a MutableList:

```
inline fun <T> MutableList<T>.transformEach(transform: (T)->T) {
    for (i in indices) {
        this[i] = transform(this[i])
    }
}
```

Then the code for your example could be converted to:

```
numbers.transformEach { if (it % 2 == 0) it * 2 else it }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to modify the list in-place, then probably the closest to your initial attempt is to use a list iterator. List iterator allows to modify the current item while iterating:

```kotlin
val numbers = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

val iter = numbers.listIterator()
iter.forEach {
    if (it % 2 == 0) {
        iter.set(it * 2)
    }
}

println(numbers)
// [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16]
```